# Writing the results of Weka classifier to file in Java

Tags: java, text-files, weka

I am generating decision trees in Weka in Java code as follows:

```
        J48 j48DecisionTree = new J48();   
        Instances data = null;
        data = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dt.getArffFile())));              
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
        j48DecisionTree.buildClassifier(data);
```

Can I save the results of the Weka results buffer to a text file in the program, such that the following can be saved at run-time to a text file:

> === Stratified cross-validation ===
>        === Summary ===

```
Correctly Classified Instances         229               40.1754 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       341               59.8246 %
Kappa statistic                          0.2022
Mean absolute error                      0.1916
Root mean squared error                  0.3138
Relative absolute error                 80.8346 %
Root relative squared error             91.1615 %
Coverage of cases (0.95 level)          96.3158 %
 Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)      70.9774 %
Total Number of Instances              570     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

           TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
             0.44      0.012      0.786     0.44      0.564      0.76     Business and finance and economics
             0         0          0         0         0          0.616    Fashion and celebrity lifestyle
             0.125     0.01       0.667     0.125     0.211      0.663    Film
             0         0.002      0         0         0          0.617    Music
             0.931     0.78       0.318     0.931     0.474      0.633    News and current affairs
             0.11      0.006      0.786     0.11      0.193      0.653    Science and nature and technology
             0.74      0.012      0.86      0.74      0.796      0.85     Sport
```

Weighted Avg.    0.402     0.224      0.465     0.402     0.316      0.667

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   <-- classified as
 22   0   0   0  25   2   1 |   a = Business and finance and economics
  0   0   1   0  59   0   0 |   b = Fashion and celebrity lifestyle
  0   0  10   1  69   0   0 |   c = Film
  0   0   1   0  69   0   0 |   d = Music
  5   0   2   0 149   0   4 |   e = News and current affairs
  1   0   0   0  87  11   1 |   f = Science and nature and technology
  0   0   1   0  11   1  37 |   g = Sport
```

dt is an instance of a class of mine to represent decision tree details.

As I'm running a large number of classifiers, this would help somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. But you need to create an instance of Evaluation in Weka and call the appropriate methods from the instance:

```
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
eval.evaluateModel(j48DecisionTree, data);
System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", true));
```

Will give a summary.

But then methods such as:

```
eval.pctCorrect();
```

Can be called. See [Weka Javadoc](http://bio.informatics.indiana.edu/ml_docs/weka/weka.classifiers.Evaluation.html) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

The Weka classifiers have an extensive `#toString()` method, which gives you a human readable representation, in this case the tree. You can also use `#toSource(String)` to get a Java code equivalent for the decision tree.

If you want to store the model for re-using it later, have a look at `weka.core.SerializationHelper`.

Comment: I am able to output the trees using #toString. It is the results of the classification I'm after though. I have edited the question to show the data I mean.