# How to get "Mean rel. region size" using WEKA API

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I use the WEKA API in my Java code to customize the output of metrics from generated training classifiers.

I was simulating the result buffer in the Explorer section of the GUI version (result buffer taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12699059/1685185)):

```
Correctly Classified Instances         229               40.1754 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       341               59.8246 %
Kappa statistic                          0.2022
Mean absolute error                      0.1916
Root mean squared error                  0.3138
Relative absolute error                 80.8346 %
Root relative squared error             91.1615 %
Coverage of cases (0.95 level)          96.3158 %
Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)      70.9774 %
Total Number of Instances              570
```

Majority have been straightforward in terms of method call and Javadocs ie. to get the `Kappa statistic`, its equivalent method with respect to an [`Evaluation` object](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) is: `evaluation.kappa()`.

I came across the `Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)` item and I couldn't find an obvious equivalent in the Javadocs.

I want to know if this is available for the `Evaluation` or do I have to compute it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Hall provided a hint to how `Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)` is obtained in the Explorer section in his answer to ["*Rel. Region*"](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Rel-Region-tp24399p24400.html):

> This is part of the evaluation of computed confidence bounds on the 
>   predictions made by the classifier. From the Javadocs for the method 
>   that is used to produce this output:
>
> > "Gets the average size of the predicted regions, relative to the range of 
> >     the target in the training data, at the confidence level specified when 
> >     evaluation was performed."

A quick <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the [`Evaluation` Javadocs](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) revealed that `Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)` is actually the method [`sizeOfPredictedRegions()`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#sizeOfPredictedRegions%28%29).